# How to use another field for logging in with Django Allauth?

Tags: django, model

I have successfully setup `django-allauth` along with a custom user model which let's users sign in directly using email and password or through Facebook, in which case email is taken from Facebook and saved in the Email field of the custom user model. I have also created a mobile field which stays empty as of now.

I want to allow users to log in using their Facebook, Email or MOBILE. Unfortunately that field is not `unique=True` in the model. I have thought of capturing the mobile and fetching the associated email address and then use that along with the password to log in any user.

However, I don't know how to extend the SIGN IN form that comes with `django-allauth` or the block of code that signs a user in where I can change it to meet my need.

As of now I don't find any of my current code relevant to this problem, but if it helps I am willing to provide it upon mention.

Comment: You can override different form classes with `ACCOUNT_FORMS` or `SOCIALACCOUNT_FORMS`. Please see http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html.

Comment: @twil I have used `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'alpha.forms.SignupForm'` in the settings and created a form in `forms.py` with `first_name`, `last_name` and `mobile` to add these three fields to the fields that are already there. How can I use `ACCOUNT_FORMS (={})` to override the `email` field and change it to `mobile` field? Please note that I have to change the underlying code too. I am going to use `email` and `password` to verify the user. But when they log in with mobile, I will fetch the email with the mobile. Do you know how I can change the login code along with the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution worked for me. I put the code in the `forms.py` file.

```
from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm
from auth_project import settings

class CustomLoginForm(LoginForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if settings.ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD == "email":
            login_widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'text',
                                                  'placeholder':
                                                  ('Mobile Number'),
                                                  'autofocus': 'autofocus'})
            login_field = forms.CharField(label=("Mobile"),
                                           widget=login_widget)
        self.fields["login"] = login_field
        set_form_field_order(self,  ["login", "password", "remember"])

    def user_credentials(self):
        credentials = {}
        mobile = self.cleaned_data["login"]
        login = CustomUser.objects.filter(mobile=mobile).values('email')[0]['email']
        if settings.ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD == "email":
            credentials["email"] = login
        credentials["password"] = self.cleaned_data["password"]
        return credentials

# this is to set the form field in order
# careful with the indentation
def set_form_field_order(form, fields_order):
    if hasattr(form.fields, 'keyOrder'):
        form.fields.keyOrder = fields_order
    else:
        # Python 2.7+
        from collections import OrderedDict
        assert isinstance(form.fields, OrderedDict)
        form.fields = OrderedDict((f, form.fields[f])
                                  for f in fields_order)
```

Thanks.