# Adding a new field along with username and password in django's login form

Tags: python, django

I want to edit the login form provided by django and don't want to build a new one because of the security issues. I have looked at other solutions like [How to use another field for logging in with Django Allauth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244477/how-to-use-another-field-for-logging-in-with-django-allauth) it's a good example but it assigns email id based on mobile number. However I want to add another field that isn't particularly to authenticate just for input based on which redirection is done. I am quite confused about my approach and whether or not it is possible to do so. Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in your forms.py file by doing this.

```
class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Password'}))
    yourfield = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'yourfield'}))
    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")

        #user_qs = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        #if user_qs.count() == 1:
        #   user = user_qs.first()
        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if not user:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This user does not exist")
            if not user.check_password(password):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect password")
            if not user.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This user is no longer active")
            return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I've misunderstood your question, but here is how I've added extra fields to user registration it which seems pretty straightforward. I've included some extra related methods just to be verbose:

../forms.py:

```
class CustomRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    """
    Form for registering a new user account.

    Subclasses should feel free to add any additional validation they
    need, but should avoid defining a ``save()`` method -- the actual
    saving of collected user data is delegated to the active
    registration backend.

    """
    username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                                max_length=30,
                                label="Username",
                                error_messages={'invalid': "This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters."})

    email = forms.EmailField(label="E-mail")
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                label="Password")
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                label="Password (again)")

    extra_field = forms.CharField([field options])


    def clean(self):

        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError("The two password fields didn't match.")
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Then, simply set your register URL to use the proper form class:

../urls.py:

```
url(r'^accounts/register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=accounts.forms.CustomRegistrationForm), name='registration_register'),
```

Is this field not part of your standard model, or does your input need to do some extra work? You can set a signal to make some extra magic happen when the user is registered:

```
from forms import CustomRegistrationForm
def user_created(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    form = CustomRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    user_account = get_user_account(user)
    user_account.persona = form.data['persona_tier']
    user_account.save()

from registration.signals import user_registered
user_registered.connect(user_created)
```

FYI I'm using django-registration-redux backend but this approach should help get you close regardless.